# What is the downside of adding '__init__.py' in sub-directories of a Python codebase if certain directories do not have that file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython

Since Python 3.3, the compulsion for having an `__init__.py` in every directory of a source code was removed. My aim is to read all the modules and submodules of a given source code using `pyclbr`. However, there are certain cases where a particular module is a submodule to other modules and not all the parent modules are packages. `pyclbr` does not understand the difference between directories and packages.

So, while [attempting to solve this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62237157/how-to-use-pyclbr-for-nested-modules/66298227#66298227), I thought of adding the `__init__.py` file in every directory that is not a package. I am not sure as to what the downsides are. I have this inhibition of deviating from the standards set by the Python community and that might result in incorrectness sometime later.

As stated in the above hyperlink, I could go with specifying only the module and give its full-path to `pyclbr` but that does not work in cases like the following source code structure:

```
(gruml) ➜  gruml git:(run-sequence-diagram) ✗ tree a
a
└── a
    └── a
        ├── __init__.py
        └── a.py

2 directories, 2 files
```

This does not work because sending `a` to `pyclbr` would return the same data for `a.a.a` and for `a.a.a.a`. So, I have to send the full-module path and work for directories.

Answer (score 0):

> would return the same data for `a.a.a` and for `a.a.a.a`

Since I'm not familiar with `pyclbr`, it's unclear what data you're referring to, but if you want something specific to only `a.a.a`, then that would be need to be written inside of the init file